# wxPython widget not centered vertically

Tags: checkbox, wxpython, wxwidgets, centering

I am trying to center a CheckBox widget vertically inside a panel. I cannot figure out why it's aligned to the top.

I had to create a Panel for the CheckBox because without that the background looks ugly (Windows 10 -- see second image)

Thanks for suggestions!

```
class wxUIE(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):


        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(800, 400), title=title)

        self.editorText = wx.TextCtrl (self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE+wx.SUNKEN_BORDER+wx.TE_BESTWRAP)

        self.myBar = wx.TextCtrl (self, -1)
        # Checkbox
        self.myCheckBoxPanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1, 25))
        self.myCheckBox = wx.CheckBox(self.myCheckBoxPanel, label="Highlight",  style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.sizer.Add(self.editorText, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.myBar, 10, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.myCheckBoxPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizeHints(800,400)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Show()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wxUIE(None, "My Edit Control")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[CheckBox aligned to top of panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/famMH.png)

[CheckBox is aligned vertically correctly but the background sucks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7jJi.png)

Comment: can you try wx.CENTER_VERTICAL, instead of wx.EXPAND. Check the docs for proper name.

Comment: I am seeing an error "AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'CENTER_VERTICAL' " -- using 'wx.ALIGN_CENTER' as described [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp) did not help either.

Comment: Got it right with 2 changes:    `self.searchCheckBox = wx.CheckBox(self.searchCheckBoxPanel, label="Highlight", size=(-1, 25))` and `self.sizer2.Add(self.searchCheckBoxPanel, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)` Thanks very much!

Comment: sorry, didn't see it at first. You should get rid of the size parameter to the constructor. Both position and size of the control will be managed for you by sizers. Sizers will help you manage the cross-platform difference and will size the control properly for whatever font the OS will use.